How to stop airflow webserver?
I followed this tutorial to install apache airflow on my mac inside conda environment with python version 3.11.
Now I want to close the airflow webserver but I'm not able to.
So I tried this solution. But it is not working.
(base) giteshwarmali@Giteshwars-MacBook-Pro orchestration % kill $(ps -o ppid= -p $(cat ~/Desktop/orchestration/airflow-webserver.pid))
kill: kill 1 failed: operation not permitted

I also removed the airflow-webserver.pid file from airflow home.
I tried to list all the airflow processes. and kill them using their pid, but to no avail. I tried with sudo also.
(base) giteshwarmali@Giteshwars-MacBook-Pro orchestration % ps aux | grep airflow                                                           
giteshwarmali    63441   0.0  0.6 413550416 106944   ??  S    11:46PM   0:00.62 /Users/giteshwarmali/anaconda3/envs/data-engineering/bin/python3.11 -m gunicorn --workers 4 --worker-class sync --timeout 120 --bind 0.0.0.0:8081 --name airflow-webserver --pid /Users/giteshwarmali/Desktop/orchestration/airflow-webserver.pid --config python:airflow.www.gunicorn_config --access-logfile - --error-logfile - airflow.www.app:cached_app() --preload
giteshwarmali    65986   0.0  0.0 410199776   1136 s011  S+    7:51AM   0:00.00 grep airflow
(base) giteshwarmali@Giteshwars-MacBook-Pro orchestration % kill -9 63441
kill: kill 63441 failed: no such process
(base) giteshwarmali@Giteshwars-MacBook-Pro orchestration % kill -9 65986
kill: kill 65986 failed: no such process

Can you please help, what could be going wrong?

I don't know but after waiting for around 10 15 minutes, The airflow website was down by itself. and now I'm able to trigger it again and working fine.

I don't remember now But the issue probably was that I usedcommand + z to stop the server. which put it to sleep. i guess.
